# How to use google drive video embedded via iframe without video controls?

Tags: html, video, iframe, controls

I want to remove control from video. Any Solution to remove video controls?

I'm trying to use a google drive video using embed iframe and it works good, but I have tried to remove control using Controls="false" in iframe, but it does not works. Any other way to remove video controls from iframe video?

Comment: GDrive video player is very limited, your best bet might be to use a standard video player (HTML tag, plry.io etc) and follow these instructions to get the direct link https://bytesbin.com/play-google-drive-video-in-vlc/